# Naming Vars with strings

Tags: string, variables, code-generation, naming-conventions

Can a variable be named with a string or character array, in any language? Basically I want something like:

```
Var_String = "varname"
Var_String as double
```

And then I could fill the `double varname`.
If it helps im trying to make a program that can declare variables on the fly, while running. Even if thats not possible, I am open to workarounds even if they're impractical, although I would prefer that workarounds be in VB6, C++, or PHP, because I know those languages already, but they dont have to be.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is completely capable of declaring variable names on the fly. A javascript object can be treated "associatively" as a dictionary. Observe:

```
var testyObject = function()
{
    Awesome = "hello";
};

var myObject = new testyObject();

alert(myObject.Awesome); // creates an alert window that says hello
alert(myObject['Awesome']); // the same as above
myObject[myObject.Awesome] = "woo!"; // We just created a property on the object with the name "hello"
alert(myObject.hello); // creates an alert window that says "woo!"
```

I also believe you can add them to your immediate scope rather than as properties on other objects by using `this["whatever you want it named"] = "woo!";` but I'm not certain, someone can correct me on that if such does not work.

You can read more about associative arrays at http://www.quirksmode.org/js/associative.html

Comment: Ok i kind of get what you're saying. From what i know about javascript(which isnt much) it's  used for browser based things right? I'm thinking stand alone apps.  And is javascript related to the java language? Ill probably learn that soon so if they are this might be helpful. Sorry if that is... inconvenient or uniformed. Im just a few notches above novice.

Comment: With what you're doing do you actually just maybe want a dictionary? It's a list of KeyValuePairs and you can index to the value by using the key, HashTable and Map are two other data structures that behave similarly (dictionaries usually are hashtables under the covers with collission safety). I was merely trying to answer your question regarding if it is possible in any language. Javascript is completely unrelated to Java though it may appear to be, this was a common and dangerous misconception in the early days of javascript.

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to do something like this is called a hash.  You store name/value pairs and given the name, can look up its value.  You can generally define them to store any sort of object.  In fact, in some languages, objects themselves are essentially hashes with a few extra properties.

You can find more information on wikipedia:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table